# Linq query with many to many relations using entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables: `tbA` and `tbB` .Between them I have a relationship n to n, so a table `tbAB` was generated in the database. I am using an Entity Framework Database First, then when I mapped these tables , it does not generate a specific entity for `tbAB`. Thus , I'm not seeing how I can create a query relating the two tables if I can't call directly the`tbAB`.
What I want to do in SQL would be as follows :

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM tbA
 INNER JOIN tbAB 
 ON tbAB.idA = tbA.idA
 INNER JOIN tbB
 ON tbB.idB = tbAB.idB
```

That's what I'm trying to do with Linq:

```
  var table = (from l in db.tbA
                                            join k in db.tbB on l.? equals k.?
                                            where ?.IDCONCESSAO == objectTbB.IDCONCESSAO
                                            select l).ToList();
```

The question is how can I do this in a Linq expression ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please rename tables to generic table A and TableB, easier to read! especially for non italian(i think) speaking? And include generic Ids

Comment: Ok, I think now is better...

Comment: EF will do it for you as long as you have navigation properties

Comment: Is `tbAB` a temporary table or view, or does it truly exist as a static table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the model proposed by @Michal, you could do this:

```
var query= from a in db.TableAs
           from b in a.TableBs
           where b.Id==10
           select new{A_Id=a.Id,a.Name, B_Id=b.Id,b.Price,...};
```

In the `select` you can choose the properties you need from both entities(I also select a `Name` from `TableA` and a `Price` from `TableB`to help you understand better this example).From each direction of the relationship, you don’t ever interact with the [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table), you just follow a relationship from each direction as if it were a one-to-many. The query that I show above will be translated in a sql query where the joins between the tables will be made this way:

```
{SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Join1].[Id] AS [Id1], 
[Join1].[Price] AS [Price]
FROM  [dbo].[TableAs] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[TableA_Id] AS [TableA_Id], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent3].[Price] AS [Price]
    FROM  [dbo].[TableBTableAs] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TableBs] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent2].[TableB_Id] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Join1].[TableA_Id]
WHERE 10 = [Join1].[Id]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void Test()
    {
        var db = new DbContext();

        // This will automatically do you inner join for you.
        db.TableAs.Include(a => a.TableBs);
    }
```

Context:

```
    public class DbContext
    {
        public IDbSet<TableA> TableAs { get; set; }
        public IDbSet<TableB> TableBs { get; set; }
    }
```

Models:

```
    public class TableA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual List<TableB> TableBs { get; set; }
    }
    public class TableB
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual List<TableA> TableAs { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thx Michal, but how I do a restriction like this: `SELECT * 
 FROM tbA
 INNER JOIN tbAB 
 ON tbAB.idA = tbA.idA
 INNER JOIN tbB
 ON tbB.idB = tbAB.idB where tbAB.idB = 10`

Answer (score 0):

```
  var table = from a in db.tbA
              join ab in db.tbAB on a.idA  equals ab.idA
              join b in db.tbB on ab.idB  equals b.idB
              where a.Anything = 10
              select a;

  var results = table.ToList();
```

Comment: There is no `db.tbAB`.  EF detects n-n relationships (where there is a tie table containing only keys) and represents them as just relationships even though there is a table in SQL.  If you add non-key fields then there will be an entity representing that table.

Comment: Yeh but when you add these tables to designer . it will show the appropriate table name with db entity object. this code is just to show how to relate those 3 tables to each other. @pseudocoder